# Add prefix before string value in java

Tags: java, android

I have above in my java file, value of identity is coming from another page and its numeric value. Now i this page i want to add letter "V" before value identity string. so let say if value of string identity comes to this page as 5678 then i want it to become V5678 before it goes to last line

Can anyone help me with this ?

Here is code:

```
private static String identity;

identity = helper.getSettingValueGeneratedId();

Ion.with(this).load(SERVER_URL + "?identity=" + identity).asString().setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>()
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply append "V" at the beginning of the `String`:

```
identity = "V" + helper.getSettingValueGeneratedId();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can end up using a StringBuilder for this.

So something like:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("V");
sb.append(helper.getSettingValueGeneratedId());
//and then simply do 
sb.toString();
//when you call identity
```

or the manual way would be to do:

```
identity = "V" + helper.getSettingValueGeneratedId();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String concatenation! Change your 2nd line of code to:

```
identity = "V" + helper.getSettingValueGeneratedId();
```

:)